# Double sequence, if $(x_m)_m$ and $(y_n)_n$ converge, then they have the same limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_{m, n})_{m, n}$ be a "double sequence" of real numbers; that is, for every pair $(m, n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, $a_{m, n}$ is a real number. Suppose that, for every $m$, $(a_{m, n})_n$ converges to a limit $x_m$, and that for every $n$ the sequence $(a_{m, n})_m$ converges to a limit $y_n$. Suppose that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{m, n} - x_m| < \epsilon$ and $|a_{m, n} - y_n| < \epsilon$ for every $m$, $n > N$. Does it follow that if $(x_m)_m$ and $(y_n)_n$ converge, then they have the same limit?

Comment: It seems to me like you're just [posting a bunch of analysis exercises](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634764/double-sequence-two-sequences-converge-but-to-different-limits) ([this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634726/example-of-two-sequences-a-n-and-b-n-such-that-both-of-them-are-bounded) might be you as well). What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can make the difference between $x_m$ and $y_n$ arbitrarily small for large $m$ and $n$, if one of the sequences converges to a limit $a$ then so does the other:

$$\forall k>N:|x_k-y_k|\leq|x_k-a_{k,k}|+|a_{k,k}-y_k|<2\epsilon.$$

Comment: I don't think this is enough.

Comment: I have made the reasoning slightly more explicit.